# id.style or document.getElementById('id').style

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to add style ?

Using

`id.style.color = "green"` or `document.getElementById('id').style.color = "green"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latter option:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.color = "green"
```

See this answer for a good write-up on this issue:

- [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/247441)

> It's generally considered bad practice to omit var, as well as to rely on named elements being visible on window or as globals. Stick to document.getElementById, which is more widely-supported and less ambiguous.